# How do i add a button that on clicking will take me to the product page with more product description along with comments and rating

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, e-commerce

I'm trying to do a project for uni and am stuck at this one particular part.
I'm trying to display a button that would open a specific product and let users order/add to cart/rate it

I've almost very little knowledge of java script and started PHP about 2months back.
Here is my code.

```
$sql="select * from products";
$rs=$db->query($sql);
echo "<form method='post' action=viewitem.php>";
echo "<table>";
foreach ($rs as $row) {
    $id=$row[0];
    echo "<tr><td><img src = '/3331/333/bootstrap-shop/pimages/MensShirts/$row[6]' width='250' height='250'></td>
          <td><pre>$row[5]</pre></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>$row[3] - <strong>BD$row[4]</strong></td></tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='$id' value='View more'/></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

The form I'm submitting to is

```
$pid=$id;
$sql="select * from products where pid='$pid'";
$rs=$db->query($sql);
echo "<form method='post' action=addtocart.php>";
echo "<table>";
foreach ($rs as $row) {
    $id=$row[0];
    echo "<tr><td><img src = '/3331/333/bootstrap-shop/pimages/MensShirts/$row[6]' width='250' height='250'></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>$row[3] - <strong>BD$row[4]</strong></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

I'm supposed to add more items there but I cant seem to find out what product the user has exactly clicked on. it keeps saying `$pid/$id` are undefined.

Comment: This is not how it works. Please read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: i understand well how forms work and appreciate your reply. As you can see each product will have its own submit button as its inside a foreach loop. i want to be able to name this submit button the same name as the product ID in my database so i can compare the values and display information. Moreover, im using 'extract($_POST)' instead of getting each element alone is that okay>

Comment: What is `name='$id'` mean to do? How are you getting that value back in PHP after form submission?

Comment: <input type='submit' name='$id' value='View more'/> will result in a POST named with the value of $id. For instance, if the value of the '$id' variable is '3'. you can access it via $_POST['3']. If you used extract($_POST) the result is, you have a variable named $3 whose value will be 'View more'.

Comment: I was trying to get the ID from the name of the input sumbit and want aware you cant use php variables in that manner. Thanks to user below me he reminded me of the GET method (i started learning php less than 2 months back). I'd appreciate if you weren't harsh as im just trying to learn and not bother anyone.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of submitting a form to view a product, simply create a link and pass the product id as a parameter.

For example, on your listings page you would have...

```php
<?php $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM products" ); ?>
<table>
    <?php foreach ( $query as $row ): ?>
        <tr><td><img src="/3331/333/bootstrap-shop/pimages/MensShirts/<?php echo $row[ 6 ]; ?>" width="250" height="250"></td>
        <td><pre><?php echo $row[ 5 ]; ?></pre></td></tr>
        <tr><td><?php echo $row[ 3 ]; ?> - <strong>BD<?php echo $row[ 4 ]; ?></strong></td></tr>
        <td><a href="viewitem.php?id=<?php echo $row[ 0 ]; ?>">View more</a></tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Specifically `<a href="viewitem.php?id=<?php echo $row[ 0 ]; ?>">View more</a>`

When clicked this will take the user to a URL something like: `http://example.com/viewitem.php?id=123`

And then in the `viewitem.php` file we grab the `id` parameter from the URL and perform the query. For example:

```php
<?php

$pid = !empty( $_GET[ 'id' ] ) ? (int)$_GET[ 'id' ] : null;

if ( $pid ) {
    $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM products WHERE pid = {$pid}" );
    ?>
        <form method="post" action="addtocart.php">
            <table>
                <?php foreach ( $query as $row ): ?>
                    <tr><td><img src="/3331/333/bootstrap-shop/pimages/MensShirts/<?php echo $row[ 6 ]; ?>" width="250" height="250"></td>
                    <tr><td><?php echo $row[ 3 ]; ?> - <strong>BD<?php echo $row[ 4 ]; ?></strong></td></tr>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </table>
        </form>
    <?php
} else {
    echo 'No product ID';
}
```

URL parameters are accessible via the `$_GET` array but because we will be using the value of this parameter in the SQL query we have to sanitise the data as you'll be susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

The below line is basically checking if the `id` parameter exists in the url, if it does make sure it's a valid integer.

```php
$pid = !empty( $_GET[ 'id' ] ) ? (int)$_GET[ 'id' ] : null;
```

This is the same as...

```
$pid = null;
if ( !empty( $_GET[ 'id' ] ) ) {
    $pid = (int)$_GET[ 'id' ];
}
```

Now for a quick example of what can happen if you don't sanitise the input data...

If you passed the `$_GET[ 'id' ]` value directly into the sql query, for example:

```php
$db->query( "SELECT * FROM products WHERE pid = " . $_GET[ 'id' ] );
```

An attacker could then start running their own SQL queries on your database, so if they visited `http://example.com/viewitem.php?id=1; SELECT * FROM users;` the following query would be run...

```sql
SELECT * FROM products WHERE pid = 1; SELECT * FROM users;
```

This is a very basic example of SQL injection, I would highly recommend researching it in more depth.

Comment: thankyou so much for this, i really appreciate the help! im aware of sql injection but don't know much about it. Do you recommend any books/videos/websites where i can learn more about PHP? the uni i go to is low budget so they only brush over the very basics. i mostly end up using youtube to learn.